# Entity Framework GroupBy, FirstOrDefault and async thread safety

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

Is this a safe code to write in Entity Framework?

```
var apartmentQuery = ctx.apartmentRooms.OrderBy(m => m.ID)
                 .GroupBy(m => new { m.Apartment.Activity.CreatedBy, m.ApartmentID })
                 .Take(20)
                 .Select(m => m.FirstOrDefault());


                var list = await apartmentRooms.ToListAsync();
```

Since `FirstOrDefault` is in the code, is it possible to get EF threading problems while awaiting `ToListAsync`?

Comment: Does `apartmentRooms.ToList();` return the correct values? Are you running concurrent queries using the same context? Have you looked at the generated SQL query or profiled it to see if the correct query is being generated? There are no EF threading issues with `FirstOrDefault` because it will be translated into the query and run on the database server.

Comment: It works well with ToList and ToListAsync, but once I got EF error about concurrent queries in the same context, and was never able to reproduce it again, so I am not sure was the error caused by this code.

Comment: @PauloMorgado it seems to be that everything is in order, so if you copy your comment as an answer, I will mark it as answered :)

Comment: EF contexts do not support concurrent queries.